# How to resolve TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for <encoded text> with type list

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, bert-language-model

I'm creating a multiclass classifier in Python using BERT and Tensorflow 2.*, but I'm encountering two errors with my current code that I've been stuck on all day. The first error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for [[<encoded text>], [...]] with type list
```

Where `[<encoded text>]` looks like:

```
[101, 1997, 5142, 2000, 1996, 5438, 10994, 2003, 3465, 1997, 5438, 2004, 2092, 8521, 2011, 1011, 4031, 2030, 2512, 1011, 3151, 14172, 2029, 2097, 4254, 14266, 1998, 2740, 102]
```

The second error I'm getting is:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ValueError: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor.
```

For the second error, I'm considering using ragged tensors, so any help on that would be greatly appreciated. However, I'm mostly focused on figuring out the first error since I've spent so long on it.

My errors are coming from the `encode_examples` function, and my script is:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from transformers import BertTokenizer
from transformers import TFBertForSequenceClassification

# This is a path to an uncased (all lowercase) version of BERT
BERT_MODEL_HUB = "https://tfhub.dev/google/bert_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1"

# Hyperparameters
BATCH_SIZE = 1
LEARNING_RATE = 2e-5  # recommended learning rate for Adam 5e-5, 3e-5, 2e-5
NUMBER_OF_EPOCHS = 1

tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()


def get_input_data(file_name, is_labelled=False):
    """
    Returns file data

    :param file_name: name of file to be read
    :param is_labelled: True if file name is labelled
    :return: input_list: list containing file data
    """
    input_list = []
    if is_labelled:
        input_list = {}
    with open(file_name, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        if is_labelled:
            file_list = list(f)
            label = file_list[0].rstrip()
            sentences = file_list[1:]
            for sentence in sentences:
                input_list[sentence] = label
        else:
            rows = iter(csv.reader(f))
            next(rows)
            for row in rows:
                if len(row) < 2:
                    continue
                input_list.append([e.replace("_", " ") for e in row])
    return input_list


def combine_files(*args) -> dict:
    """
    Combines files and returns list of their data
    :return: combined_inputs List of input data from files
    """
    combined_data = {}
    for file in args:
        combined_data.update(get_input_data(file, True))
    return combined_data


def encode_data(text_dict: dict) -> dict:
    """
    Converts labels into integers
    :param text_dict: mapping of text to label
    :return: mapping of text to integer label
    """
    for key in text_dict.keys():
        val = text_dict[key]
        if val == 'negative':
            text_dict[key] = 0
        elif val == 'neutral':
            text_dict[key] = 1
        else:
            text_dict[key] = 2
    return text_dict


def split_data(data: dict) -> (list, list, list, list):
    """
    Splits data into train/test
    :param data: maps labels to data
    :return: X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test
    """
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(list(data.keys()),
                                                        list(data.values()),
                                                        test_size=0.33,
                                                        random_state=42)
    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test


def create_df(source: list, target: list) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Creates pandas DataFrame from data as follows:

           Text            Sentiment
    0      <sentence>      <sentiment>
    ...    ...             ...
    N      <sentence>      <sentiment>
    """
    return pd.DataFrame(data=[[txt, sent] for txt, sent in zip(source, target)],
                        columns=['Text', 'Sentiment'])


def map_example_to_dict(input_ids, attention_masks, token_type_ids, label):
    return {
               "input_ids": input_ids,
               "token_type_ids": token_type_ids,
               "attention_mask": attention_masks,
           }, label


def convert_example_to_feature(txt):
    return tz.encode_plus(
        txt,
        add_special_tokens=True,
        max_length=160,
        truncation=True,
        return_token_type_ids=True,
        return_attention_mask=True,
        padding=True,
    )


def encode_examples(ds, limit=-1):
    # prepare list, so that we can build up final TensorFlow dataset from slices.
    input_ids_list = []
    token_type_ids_list = []
    attention_mask_list = []
    label_list = []
    if limit > 0:
        ds = ds.take(limit)

    for txt, label in tfds.as_numpy(ds):
        bert_input = convert_example_to_feature(str(txt[0].decode("UTF-8")))
        print(bert_input, "\n")

        input_ids_list.append(bert_input['input_ids'])
        token_type_ids_list.append(bert_input['token_type_ids'])
        attention_mask_list.append(bert_input['attention_mask'])
        label_list.append([label])
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (input_ids_list, attention_mask_list, token_type_ids_list, label_list)).map(map_example_to_dict)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = combine_files("neg_sentiment.txt", "neu_sentiment.txt", "pos_sentiment.txt")
    encoded = encode_data(data)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = split_data(encoded)
    train = create_df(X_train, y_train)
    test = create_df(X_test, y_test)
    # print(train["Text"].head())

    tz = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", do_lower_case=True)

    train_target, test_target = train.pop('Sentiment'), test.pop('Sentiment')
    ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train.values, train_target.values))
    ds_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test.values, test_target.values))

    ds_train_encoded = encode_examples(ds_train).shuffle(10000).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    ds_test_encoded = encode_examples(ds_test).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

    model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE, epsilon=1e-08)

    loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=[metric])
```

Comment: which line generating an error ?